# How to add http interceptor in retrofit in a service generator class

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I created a separate service generator class as shown is this guide https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-manage-request-headers-in-okhttp-interceptor

ApiServiceGenerator.java

```
public class ApiServiceGenerator {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.205/hadia/api/";

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();


    public static <S> S createService(
            Class<S> serviceClass) {

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

i need to add an Authorization Header to each request,
how do i do that using this static createService method?

Here is how to create an Interceptor for adding header to each request

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "auth-value"); // <-- this is the important line

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```

How i add this method to add a Bearer token to each request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the http client created when building the retrofit instance.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)  // This is the line
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

Comment: When i add client method, it shows illegal forward reference!

Comment: This means you are referencing the `httpClient` before it is defined. Try to create a factory/constructor function to wrap both okhttp and retrofit initialization in one single static function.

Answer (score 9):

I have a `Creator` class like this

```
class Creator {
    public static Services newServices() {
        final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Services.HOST)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonUtils.get()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(Services.class);
    }
}
```