# How to parse forward slash before query

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm consuming an API in my android application using retrofit. One of the endpoints has a forward slash followed by a query.

```
http://localhost/api/trips/?userId=351da831b08e427d94c65c08b2d17642
```

However when i try to send a GET to that endpoint i do not get a response. However, when i try it on postman i get response

This is the get Request in my Retrofit API Service

```
@GET("api/trips/")
Call<GetTripsResponse> getTripsForUser(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
                                       @Header("Authorization") String token,
                                       @Query("userId") String userId);
```

And this is where i try to call it in my Code:

```
Call<GetTripsResponse> call = apiService.getTripsForUser("application/json", "Bearer " + Config.TOKEN, userId);
```

I have tried sending an empty path "Blank" in the request such that.

```
    Call<GetTripsResponse> getTripsForUser(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
                                           @Header("Authorization") String token,
                                           @Path("Blank") String blank,
                                           @Query("userId") String userId);
```

Then i adjusting my my Get Request to accept an empty string as a path such that:

```
 Call<GetTripsResponse> call = apiService.getTripsForUser("application/json", "Bearer " + Config.TOKEN, ,"",userId);
```

But still the same Empty response

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the api user id is annotated with `userId` where in the link you're it shows `dId`

replace `@Query("userId") String userId` with `@Query("dId") String userId`

Comment: I made a mistake typing the question sorry i already have userId in the link i have edited the question

Comment: did you write the  base url in retrofit client localhost?

Comment: yes i did, the issue is the forward slash in front of the query when i remove the forward slash it works but brings wrong results and the guy who built the API said the forward slash is required for correct results  i.e /?userId

Comment: post your right and wrong results. and if you are using an emulator replace localhost with your machines local ip

Comment: i dont get any response at all when i put the forward slash in url

Comment: try adding a HttpInterceptor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033743/how-to-add-http-interceptor-in-retrofit-in-a-service-generator-class
to your retrofit client to see whats happening.